# Use both JSF ajax and setPropertyActionListener tags on the same button

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I would like that when the user clicks on a button 2 things happen :

1. First a `setPropertyActionListener` is triggered, to update a property of my bean
2. Then an ajax call is made to execute a method from the bean

It seems that I must choose between the `f:setPropertyActionListener` tag and the `f:ajax` tag to nest inside the commandButton tag.

Is there a way to execute both the ajax call and the property update at the same time?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT : I forgot to mention I don't want a form execution, I want to use the ajax listener, here is my code :

```xhtml
<h:commandLink styleClass="blue-button" value="+">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{tvShowForm.selected}" value="#{tvShow.externalId}" />
  <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{tvShowForm.add}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

With this code the `f:setPropertyActionListener` is not executed.

EDIT 2 :

I modified my code to the folowing, using action form method instead of listener. Now it works only if I don't specify an event attribute on the ajax tag, but when I specify one, the action method is not executed.

```xhtml
<h:commandLink action="#{tvShowForm.add}" styleClass="blue-button" value="+">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{tvShowForm.selected}" value="#{tvShow.externalId}" />
  <f:ajax event="click" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: They will. What's the concrete problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works just for me with Mojarra 2.1.3 on Tomcat 7.0.19 and Glassfish 3.1.1.

I used this relevant piece of the view:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.value}" value="foo" />
        <f:ajax />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

with this relevant piece of the bean:

```java
private String value;

public void submit() {
    System.out.println("Value: " + value);
}

// Getter/setter.
```

which prints the following on the ajax submit:

> Value: foo

Your problem is caused by something else which you left out the question.

---

**Update**: as per your update

> *I forgot to mention I don't want a form execution, I want to use the ajax listener, here is my code :*

I really don't see why you don't want "a form execution". You **are** submitting the form. You've only left out the action method and you're doing the business job in the ajax event listener instead. The action listener methods aren't intented to do any business job, they're for at highest some self-containing processing or logging job. The model-dependent business job should be done in the action method, there it is for.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that I am trying to make it work with an ajax listener on click events. And in that case the f:setPropertyActionListener is not executed.

Comment: It is executed, but only **after** the ajax listener method. Just use the `action` method. See also answer update.

Comment: After a thought, I think that you incorrectly assumed that the `action` method is never asynchronous. This is not true. Adding `<f:ajax>` alone makes it already asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks! I modified my code in my question, but the call is not made if I specify an 'event' attribute to the ajax tag. Do you know why?

Comment: It's apparently the wrong event. It should be `action`. Just leave it away, it's already the default event.