# JSF 2.0 <f:setPropertyActionListener> is setting the target as null

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0. When I use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` in `<h:commandButton>` tag, it is setting the target property as null. If I use `<f:param>` it is working fine. What might be the problem ? Thanks, in advance.

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#searchController.sortResults}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" event="action" onevent="sortResults" render="searchResults"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener name="sortField" target="#{searchView.sortField}" value="stop" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Can you post the sample code that doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie edited with code

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861244/354831

Comment: Try to execute commandButton's id in place of @this

Comment: @Jitesh No. It's not working.

Comment: Why are you using `actionListener`? Why not simply `action`? This seems dirty to me. Try it with `action`.

Comment: `Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException:action="#{searchController.sortResults}"` If I use action I am getting the following error.

Comment: @CSK the problem might be the point where you're trying to retrieve the parameter or how you're doing it. Post your backing bean code here